# getAddressesHtmlSelect() Change - Magento

Tags: magento

I've been trying to edit the **`getAddressesHtmlSelect()`** function (found in `code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/abstract.php`) in order to enable the "new address" to display first in the dropdpown created.

I've located the place it needs to be changed in, but I can't figure out how to do that. Can anyone help? The code in question is:

```
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'_address_id')
            ->setId($type.'-address-select')
            ->setClass('address-select')
            ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
            ->setValue($addressId)
            ->setOptions($options);

        $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));

        return $select->getHtml();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for magento block rewrite. 
You need to rewrite `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing` and `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping`
Just rewrite this blocks in your custom module and define new logic for getAddressesHtmlSelect
function

To set "New address" as default one:
Assembled working sample for you.

```php
array_unshift($options, array('value' => '', 'label'=> Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address')));
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
                ->setName($type.'_address_id')
                ->setId($type.'-address-select')
                ->setClass('address-select')
                ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
                ->setOptions($options);

            return $select->getHtml();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - those blocks extend the abstract.php file above. It would seem that this bit in abstract.php file is the place to change the code, specifically in the bit I quote above. My question was how to rewrite it so that the "New Address" option will list before the other addresses are.

Comment: that's easy 
`array_unshift($options,array('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address')));`
set this code above 
`$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')`.
End remove line with `$select->addOption..`

Comment: I just tried that and now it doesn't display the words "New Address" in the dropdown - it shows a blank line. The default address selected is still billing address